# How to Show Countdown timer in HH:MM:SS (Hours : Minutes : Seconds)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, countdown, countdowntimer

How to make the countdown 'HH: mm: ss' from the XMl android that I made, when within 24 hours there is no interaction then cannot do the transaction again or cannot be accessed again

This code is design UI for countdown timer.

***Countdown Timer***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constrainlayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_color_orange"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Please make a payment Immediatelly"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constrainlayout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_TimeCountDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="13 Hour: 59 Minute: 21 Second"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_Title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:text="(Before Thursday, 16 January 2020, 13:33 WIB)"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView_Title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_Title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_TimeCountDown" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

That code will get display like this

[image: countdown timer]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's helpful for you

```
 private void startTimer(int noOfMinutes) {
        CountDownTimer  countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(noOfMinutes, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            countdownTimerText.setText(hms);//set text
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            countdownTimerText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
        }
    }.start();
```

**Edited**

```
//1584700200 is timestamp in milii seconds (Friday, March 20, 2020 10:30:00 AM) 
  //1000(1sec) is time interval to call onTick method

  new CountDownTimer(1584700200, 1000){

        @Override

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) - 
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis))), 
            (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - 
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))), (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
            countdownTimerText.setText(hms);//set text 
        }

        @Override

        public void onFinish() {
            /*clearing all fields and displaying countdown finished message          */

            countdownTimerText.setText("Count down completed");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
private fun countDown() {
    val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(1584700200, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            val millis: Long = p0
            val hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millis)),
                (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
                        millis
                    )
                )),
                (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
                        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))),
                (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                ))
            )

            System.out.println("Time : " + hms)
            countdownTimerText.setText(hms);//set text
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            /*clearing all fields and displaying countdown finished message          */
            countdownTimerText.setText("Count down completed");
            System.out.println("Time up")
        }
    }
    countDownTimer.start()
}
```

Comment: how the countdown works when the day has passed according to what is set 1 day as the picture that has a countdown of 1 day 24 hours @Nensi Kasundra

Comment: please check edited @mcode

Comment: it doesn't work I use this new code, it doesn't appear in the xml textview @Nensi Kasundra

Comment: I use it like this @Nensi Kasundra -> https://pastebin.com/mZyWKdqa

Comment: ok I will check and let you know

Comment: I already put the xml code in the question @Nensi Kasundra

Comment: ok please check edited

Comment: I have an error for Kotlin -> Expression 'TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))' of type 'Long' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: I used this code successfully but the results from the date are not what I expected, should be on (before day, date month, time) add one day not on the same day or the same date -> code me https://pastebin.com/DKGK6QNg

Comment: for that, I have to verify

Comment: Thanks for this solution! Really useful! @Nensi Kasundra

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(date2, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                long diff = date2 - cal1.getTimeInMillis();
                long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                int weeks = (int) (days / 7);
                long day = days - (weeks * 7);
                diff = diff - (days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                diff = diff - (hours * (60 * 60 * 1000));

                long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                diff = diff - (minutes * (60 * 1000));
                long seconds = diff / 1000;
                // Log.d(CommonVariables.TAG, "getCounter: " + day + " : " + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);
                tv_week.setText(weeks + "");
                tv_sec.setText(seconds + "");
                tv_min.setText(minutes + "");
                tv_hours.setText(hours + "");
                tv_days.setText(day + "");
            }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

**Happy Coding**

Comment: date2 is what I need to fill in @Praful Patel

Comment: Countdown in seconds that can function does not reduce minutes and hours, result print: -1 : -8 : -5 : -46 @Praful Patel

Comment: @mcode date2 is your source date.

Comment: But it doesn't work for minutes and hours, only runs for seconds @Praful Patel